# GWT Dynamically Changing an Image

Tags: gwt, bundle

I want to change dynamically an image by using the ID and a Ressource Bundle.

```
Element changedImage;
 /* imageID is the Id for the previous image */
 changedImage = Document.get().getElementById("imageId");
 /* And myImageBundle is the resource Bundle and icon the new image*/
 changedImage.setInnerHTML(myImageBundle.icon().getHTML());
```

But nothing happens , it's the same image . Did i miss something ?

Thanks a lot for answer(s) or suggestions(s).

-------- Solution ---------------

I've found a solution , it works properly, but somehow i think it's not the best one . Everything is on the next function :

```
    private void switchImage(  AbstractImagePrototype imageBundled) {

    String newStyleFromImageBundle, value;
    value = "style=";

    newStyleFromImageBundle = extractStyle(value ,imageBundled.getHTML());

    Element e = Document.get().getElementById("imageHeaderLogo");       
    // removing the current style
    e.removeAttribute("style");     
    // setting the new style with the  previous one retrieved from the image bundled's html
    e.setAttribute("style",newStyleFromImageBundle );


}
```

Hope it helps, feel free to tell if there's a better way to do it or this the worst you 've ever seen .. :-) .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is specifically what [applyTo](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/AbstractImagePrototype.html#applyTo%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image%29) is for. Why don't you just do the following:

```
/*assuming that the element with id "imageId" is a real image 
element and is not undefined:*/
myImageBundle.icon().applyTo(Image.wrap(Document.get().getElementById("imageId")));

//editted to use Image.wrap
```

The above should apply the image you have defined in icon() to the image with id "imageId"

Comment: I've tried what you've written but i have the next error message : "cannot cast from  element to image "  I think there's a link with what you've said 'asuming that ...' The original source for the id is   :          AbstractImagePrototype img;
  imgBundled  = getMyImageBundle().icon();
   Image image = imgBundled.createImage();
  image2.setStyleName("imageCenterPanel");
  image2.getElement().setId("imageId");

Comment: Yup, sorry about that, you can't cast an element to a widget. If you have a reference to the image created via createImage (which is what I think you meant by image2, then pass that to the applyTo instead of Document.get().getElementById("imageId"). If you don't have the reference then try casting the element to AbstractImagePrototype.ImagePrototypeElement: myImageBundle.icon().applyTo((AbstractImagePrototype.ImagePrototypeElement)Document.get().getElementById("imageId"));

Comment: You could also of course just wrap the element into an Image: ...icon().applyTo(Image.wrap(Document.get().getElementById("imageId"))

Comment: Sorry for the time i took to answer your reply.

I will try soon or later what you proposed. I'm a little bit fewer in my project.
I will get back to this part of the project and try your answer.

Thanks for having replied.